# How to make a div disappear after PHP execution with ob_flush()

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that I want to show a loading text or an image to the visitor, while it is fully loaded.
As far as I know, I should use `ob_flush();` to do so.
I tried the following code:

```
<?php

ob_start();

echo '<div> Loading </div>';

ob_end_flush();

ob_flush();
flush();

ob_start();
ob_clean();

//my php code
//my php code

?>
```

With this code everything is ok, the loading text appears first of all and then the PHP exception starts. But my problem is that after the PHP execution completes, the loading text is still on the page and it doesn't disappear.

Please help me solve this problem :)

Comment: Which exception are you talking about? Why not remove the `div` using Javascript?

Comment: @NicoHaase  Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with javascript,Please explain a little more about this or give an example about it

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not what `ob_flush()` is for. It is not possible at all with a server side language like PHP. You have to  use javascript instead.

Here is the roughly simplified and not 100% accurate description what happens when you request a PHP webpage:

1. Browser sends a request to the server "Hey server, give me page Home"
2. Server runs  the PHP script for page Home
3. Usually, the PHP script will generate some output. The server will collect this output.
4. When the script has completed, the server says "OK Browser, here is your Home page", sends the output (the response) to the browser and then **closes the connection**.
5. The connection is now closed and the server has already forgotten that the browser has even asked for a page 1 second ago.
6. The browser will happily display the newly receieved webpage. There is no way to make something happen in the browser now for your PHP script.

That's called the **Request Response Pattern** and it's still somewhat fundamental to the web.

So how can you get your loading overlay now? When you can accept that the loading overlay doesn't work on the initial page request, but everytime a user klicks a link on your site, you can use following simple approach.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Loading overlay test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="">Click me!</a>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener(
            'click',
            function() {
                if(event.target.matches('a')) {
                    document.body.innerHTML = "Loading next page ...";
                }
            },
            false
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If your page loads fast you will probably not see the effect. I kept the example as simple as possible with some plain text instead of a real loading overlay, you can use this as a starting point.

When you absolutely need an overlay for the first page request, things get more complicated. Here is a non-production ready and ajax-less example:

```php
<?php
// Detect 1st page hit
if(empty($_GET['fetch_real_page'])) {

// Loading page - keep as simple(fast) as possible, 
// prevent any slow database queries etc.
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The loading page</title>
</head>
<body>
   Loading first page...
   <script>
       // This will instantly request the "real" page
       window.location.replace(window.location.href + '?fetch_real_page=1');
   </script>
</body>
 </html>

<?php

exit; 
// (Does not need to be called explicitely
// when nothing comes after the if-else construct)

} else {

sleep(2); 
// Simulates a slow page load,
// do all the heavy database stuff that slows down your page here.
// Then, output the "real" page:
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The real page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="my_page.php?fetch_real_page=1">Click me!</a>
    <script>
        // Set up the loading overlay for secondary requests
        document.addEventListener(
            'click',
            function() {
                if(event.target.matches('a')) {
                    document.body.innerHTML = "Loading next page ...";
                }
            },
            false
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>

<?php
}
?>
```

Things to consider:

1. You need to extend every internal link with `fetch_real_page=1`
2. Sooner or later you need to deal with additional $_GET parameters, so you must extend this code, or switch to cookies or the session to check whether the request is a secondary one or not.
3. The end of the road will be a javascript/ajax-driven single page app but I think this is beyond the scope of your question.
4. Beware of this unreadable mix of PHP tags and HTML, code like that is frowned upon for good reasons. This is for demonstration only.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your explanation. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with javascript, I searched for the phrase you said, but I could not find a good example of how to embed javascript in PHP code.
Please explain a little more about this or give an example about it.